# C# Xml file read

Tags: c#, sql, xml

How to go to brother node in xml file, i want to go step back to parent node and then go step forward to brother node

```
<Kms_Section>ffffff</Kms_section>  
<Kms_Description>bbbb</kms_description>
```

Comment: Any reason you need to use the "old" XML API? With LINQ to XML you can just use `NextNode`...

Comment: i have many /KMS_doc/KMS_section then kms_section2

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question at all...

Comment: I have an already existing project the old xml api, i want to just to edit something

Comment: Are you looking for [`XmlNode.NextSibling`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.nextsibling%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Comment: it doesnt work since i have many of Kms_section tags than one Kms_section2

Comment: is there a way to go to parrent node then move to the brother like "  ../" in folders ?

Comment: 1) Parent is [`XmlNode.ParentNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.parentnode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  2) Given parent, you can find named children with [`XmlNode.SelectNodes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Maybe you want to do something like XmlNode parent = doc.SelectSingleNode("KMS_doc"); which saves KMS_Section as a Node you can use later on and then do XmlNodeList nodes = parent.SelectNodes("KMS_section"); then you work with that and after you are done you do XmlNodeList nodes = parent.SelectNodes("KMS_section2"); which of course only works if you know how the XmlDocument looks like.

Comment: I tried that                                                                                                                   if (!node.ParentNode.SelectNodes("KMS_section2/KMS_data").Item(0).Attributes["name"].Value.Contains("") to check if the attribute of the wanted node is not empty , is that correct ?

Comment: here is the full code i'm inside this node                                         XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/KMS_doc/KMS_section");                     and i need to go inside Kms_datasection

Comment: yes i edited the post above

Comment: Okay I see, so there is no actual Node called KMS_section2 inside of your Xml Document ? With KMS_section2 you meant the second KMS_section, which would be: <KMS_section name="Problème">
    <KMS_data id="problem" type="HTML">WINDOWS 7: impossible de demarrer le poste</KMS_data>
</KMS_section> is that right or does your Xml Document contain a Node that is calles KMS_section2 ?

Comment: no i meant kms_datasection i just wanted to simplify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use my earlier example. Instead of doing

```
XmlNodeList nodes =  doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/KMS_doc/KMS_section");
```

you do

```
XmlNode parent = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("KMS_doc");
```

and then you go with

```
XmlNodeList nodes = parent.SelectNodes("KMS_section");
```

you process all elements inside of nodes and then you go with

```
nodes = parent.SelectNodes("KMS_dataSection");
```

and process those elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this code to get to the next kms_section2:

```
XmlNode FoundNode = null;
while (node.NextSibling != null && FoundNode == null)
{
    node = node.NextSibling;
    if (node.Name == "kms_section2")
    {
         FoundNode = node;
    }
}
if (FoundNode != null)
{
    //Do whatever you want.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The XmlNode object has a property that is called NextSibling. It is the next node under the parent node for the specified node. But I think you just want the next node in the XmlNodeList. You can loop through them like this:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
  //Do whatever you want.
}
```